# JQuery not working on Firefox 20

Tags: jquery, firefox

Since some days I have problem on a website with the update of Firefox 20. JQuery not running on this browser with this update. I have 2 errors on my console log that I haven't the version 19 of this browser :

```
TypeError : a.getElementsByClassName(...) is undefined
ReferenceError : JQuery is not defined
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like an error in your code. What version of jQuery are you using? `getElementByClassName` would never make it through the committers (lacking `s` after `Element`).

Comment: `getElementByClassName` does not exist. I think you talk about `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Are you referencing to the jQuery library?

Comment: I would be surprised to see that code working in FF19

Comment: Given you haven't given us more of your code, this is likely unanswerable and thus "not a real question". Since you've obviously made a typo or two, it's "too localised" as well.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery needs to be the imported/loaded on the page before any script or code that relies on jQuery to run. But the first script on your page is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/wp-content/themes/child/script/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
```

Add jQuery above any other jQuery plugin's/code script.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the prototype-deprecation script.  That script sniffs for Gecko-based browsers and replaces Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName with an empty function, which of course breaks getElementsByClassName calls on elements...

Answer (score 0):

There is a new problem in firefox 20 in regards to jQuery.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/955992

Implementing the solution posted in that question thread temporarily patches the issue until firefox fixes the bug in their browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, the bug in this case is in the scripts involved, not in the browser...